# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

My chrome is giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined error when I am trying to call play function.

Here is my javascript code.

var alertSound;

```
function preload(){

  alertSound=loadSound("functions/views/sounds/beep.wav");
}
 alertSound.play();
```

Comment: What is and where is `loadSound`?

Comment: It is a predefined method used in preload function, it is to ensure that the sound is completely loaded before setup() is called

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `Audio` object where you can call the `play()` function. Something like this:

```
var alertSound;
function preload(){
  new Audio('functions/views/sounds/beep.wav')
}
alertSound.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming alertSound should be global, then you must call preload at some point and then check that alertSound is correctly initialized before calling play.

```
var alertSound;
function preload(){
  alertSound = new Audio('functions/views/sounds/beep.wav')
}

...
preload();
...

if(alertSound) alertSound.play();
```